# Alter calculated cart items total weight for a specific shipping class in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, cart

Real example: a customer had bought the following products in the cart:

1. product A, weight: 0.2kg, Qty: 2, shipping class : FREE shipping
2. product B, weight: 0.6kg, Qty: 3, shipping class: weight based shipping
3. product C, weight: 0.8kg, Qty: 1, shipping class: weight based shipping

My client is using a table rate shipping plugin, it can only calculate the shipping cost by using total cart contents weight, in this case it is 3.0kg.

But the real chargeable weight is only 2.6kg...

Had searched around and could not find any function to calculate subtotal of cart items weight for specific shipping class , so have just drafted the following function, but it seems not working. Can someone help to improve this function?

```
// calculate cart weight for certain shipping class only

    if (! function_exists('get_cart_shipping_class_weight')) {
    function get_cart_shipping_class_weight() {

        $weight = 0;
        foreach ( $this->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            if ( $value['data']->get_shipping_class() == 'shipping-from-XX' ) {
            if ( $values['data']->has_weight() ) {
                $weight += (float) $values['data']->get_weight() * $values['quantity'];
            }

        }
        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_weight', $weight ); 
     }
  }
}   

// end of calculate cart weight for certain shipping class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update *(the typo error has been corrected)*.

To make it work you need to use the dedicated `woocommerce_cart_contents_weight` filter hook in a custom hooked function this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_weight', 'custom_cart_contents_weight', 10, 1 );
function custom_cart_contents_weight( $weight ) {

    $weight = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        if ( $product->get_shipping_class() == 'shipping-from-XX' && $product->has_weight() ) {
            $weight += (float) $product->get_weight() * $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
    }
    return $weight;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works now.

Comment: Thanks LoicTtheAztec for your quick answer. Got  fatal error when using this function: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context  ….

Comment: @TonyTan Updated… Sorry I didn't pay attention as I have take that from the question code… It should work as `$this` has to be replaced by `WC()->cart` (the cart object).

Comment: did not see @reiget you have just removed the extra "->", thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Loic TheAztec, just have to remove the extra "->", perhaps your typo error, then everything works perfectly, the credit shall go to @LoicTheAztec! So the correct code should be as follows:

```
//Alter calculated cart items total weight for a specific shipping class
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_weight', 'custom_cart_contents_weight', 10, 1 );
function custom_cart_contents_weight( $weight ) {

     $weight = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
         $product = $cart_item['data'];
        if ( $product->get_shipping_class() == 'shipping-from-xx' && $product->has_weight() ) {
        // just remember to change this above shipping class name 'shipping-from-xx' to the one you want, use shipping slug
            $weight += (float) $product->get_weight() * $cart_item['quantity'];
       }  
     }
    return $weight;
 }
```

Comment: That was an accidently click on the tick not knowing it actually removes the original tick I put on your answer early, and it takes 19 hours to re-choose the answer.... It was purely misunderstanding,  sorry on the accidently click.

Comment: Ok then no problem. This answer of yours should be better deleted as it's actually exactly the same as mine, and doesn't provide anything more. It's more confusing for people than helpful.